# My Tkinter won't allow me to click the button that will show the sine wave

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter-canvas

This code won't work and I have no idea why. I'm pretty new to programming and am using a Mac, so I don't know a whole lot. I read that it might be backends of matplotlib but all the other articles were kind of inconclusive. I would like to display the wave in the GUI and would like to be able to update it with new data.

I've tried installing and uninstalling matplotlib, downloading Quartz11

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Label, Entry, Button
import pyaudio
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib. animation as animation
def insert_number():
  f=int(entry1.get())
  t=float(entry2.get())
  samples=(np.sin((f*2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*t)/(fs)).astype(np.float32)))
  stream=p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
          channels=1,
          rate=fs,
          output=True)
  stream.write(volume*samples)
  fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  def dopp():
      x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
      line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin((x)/10))
  def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(f(x + i/10.0)))
    return line,
 def init():
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
    return line,
 ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200),   init_func=init,
                             interval=25, blit=True)
  plt.show()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.window)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
canvas.draw()

start= mclass (window)
window.mainloop()
tk.mainloop()
 button2 = tk.Button (root, text='Click to see Waves ',command=insert_number)
canvas1.create_window(97, 270, window=button2)`
```

No error messages, but I know something is wrong. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Could you show your imports as well? This doesn't look like the full code.

Comment: Sorry about that! Just added them.

Comment: You are creating your button *after* the call to `.mainloop()`, which doesn't return until the window is closed (at which point you *can't* create a button).

Comment: if i move the buttons to before the button to right before this section               'start= mclass (window)...' it tells me that self is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a very similar question as to what I was asking, and I think I am supposed to define a 'PlotWindow' like a window that has the math and can just transfer the data to be displayed... If anyone could give me an idea of how that function works or kind of a general idea of what it would look like it would help a lot, I don't think I am very familiar with that. Thanks to all who replied to my original post.